# Run Shell Command with Oozie using HUE

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue

I am trying to run a simple shell script that has the following content:

```
spark-submit –class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi –master yarn-client /cloudera/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples.jar 100
```

In the shell command I write script.sh and then I add my file “script.sh” from my HDFS directory.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Kindly if you can assist.

Comment: That's not the error - it's just a log4j warning.

Comment: But my script terminates after this. The execution doesn't start.

Comment: Look at the Oozie launcher's logs, they should have the logs that show the result of the command.